# How to pass parameters to a validator of a rich:inplaceInput component

Tags: java, richfaces

I've seen [BalusC's](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/12/validator-for-multiple-fields.html) page on passing values to a validator but that is using `inputText` components.  I'm using `rich:inplaceInput` components and it doesn't seem to work.  Can someone tell me if it is possible, and if it is how to do simply?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you can add validators to rich:inplaceEdit.
Here is an example:

```
<rich:inplaceEdit required="true" value="#{myBean.name}">
  <f:validateLength minimum="3" maximum="25" />
</rich:inplaceEdit>
```

This validates that the field is filled in (required="true") and that the entered text has a length between 3 and 25 characters ().

If you don't see any error message make sure you have a message component that displays your error message and that is properly updated.

Comment: what about custom validators?

Comment: Should work as all the standard validators. They don't differ in terms of JSF as long as they implement the Validator interface.

Comment: thanks for your comments.  I want to pass values to the validator. As if to say, 'Validate the contents of the `rich:inplaceInput` and here's some other values'.  With `a4j:commandButton` you can use `f:param` but I don't think you can with `rich:inplaceInput`s.  How do I do this?